# Devise - send confirmation mail manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a landing controller looking like that:

```
class LandingsController < ApplicationController
  # POST /landing
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        LandingsMailer.thanks(@user).deliver
        format.html { render :file => File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'landing', 'thanks.html'),
                           :status => :created }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_url }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And inside `User` model, I overrided the following Devise method:

```
def send_confirmation_instructions
  if invited_at.present?
    self.confirmation_token = nil if reconfirmation_required?
    @reconfirmation_required = false

    generate_confirmation_token! if self.confirmation_token.blank?
    self.devise_mailer.confirmation_instructions(self).deliver
  end
end
```

This way, I would like to send a confirmation email to a user manually, only when `user.invited_at` is not blank (because I invited him).

This should works... but after posting a invite request with `Landing` controller, I received a Devise email with a link to confirm my email address. Just like this one:

> Welcome foo@bar.com!
>
> You can confirm your account email through the link below:
>
> Confirm my account

Do you see why? Thanks.

I'm using Devise 2.0.4 on Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3.